# Strange behavior of a COM server

Tags: c++, com

There is a COM server written in C++. Generally it works OK but sometimes at few customers there are strange problems. Clients (GUI applications) sends to the server requests for retrieving or saving some business. If clients experienced any problems they also send request to the server to log errors. In the strange situation a client gets a COM exception "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation", send error message to the server and closes itself (it has been programmed to close itself to close after such exception). The server logs the message without problems but some time after it is not working properly. It respond only to some requests (no patterns found). The server machine and the client machines have enough memory and CPU power (also when the problem appears). Restarting the server solves all the problems (until the next appearance which usually happens in a couple of days).

Has somebody any idea what me be the problem?

Thank you in advance
Lukasz

Comment: You assert that the server has enough memory, but not how you know that this is true.  It would be useful to know if the server is running as 32bit or 64bit.  In 32bit memory fragmentation could be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is far too little information to determine accurately the cause of the problem. Sure, threading issues could cause this, but there are dozens of similar causes that could have the same result.

Behind the scenes, this is `HRESULT: 0x8007000E (E_OUTOFMEMORY)`. The question is who generates this result; is it the COM interop or your server code?

Comment: Well, could be a non-terminated string being marshalled, for instance, or an array with incorrect length (e.g. set to -1 on a previous error). We really can't tell from the question.